# Regex Select ".." And not "..."

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Essentially I have a string:
string str = "Hello.... My name is Steve.. I like Dogs."

I need to change occurrences of "..." or more periods into just 3. Any occurrences of 2 need to become 1.

Using

`Regex.Replace(str)`

`Regex.Replace(str,"[.]{3,}","...")` works great at changing the groups greater then 3 to 3.
But I can't select groups of 2 "[.]{2}" because the groups of 3 are made up of 2...

My final String needs to look like this:
`string str = "Hello... My name is Steve. I like Dogs."`

Comment: Why must be regex?

Comment: Doesnt need to be regex, If you know of a different method please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex with negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<!\.)\.\.(?!\.)
```

Comment: I like this more then the other answer though as it is pure regex

Comment: @JasonBrown Try `(?<!\.)\.\.(?!\.)|\.{3,}` regex, because it covers both 'more then 3 dots' and '2 dots' cases.

Comment: But im using a regex.replace so wouldnt that replace both groups? What I want is to replace the 2 dots with 1 dot, and 3 or more dots with 3 dots.

Comment: @JasonBrown Fair enough for personal preference, but if it's easier to do without a regex than with one, then there's a good chance a regex is not the best tool for the job. And your comment suggests that you don't really understand what this regex does yet: no, it wouldn't replace both groups.

Comment: @JasonBrown You're right. Now I have realized, that you should use two separate regexes for both groups, because you have two different replacement strings.

Comment: I was going to say, I just tested that expression and it replaced both groups. But yes the way I have it now works nicely, However if there is a better way to do this that doesnt use regex I would prefer it. Since regex seems to take a while to calculate things, compared to alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use c# features:

```
string input = "Hello.... My name is Steve.. I like Dogs.";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\.{2,}", m => m.Length == 2 ? "." : "...");
```